# SQL - Count Partition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a massive table, a snippet of which goes like this:

```
ID  | Archive   | Open Account Date
Bob | May 2018  | Jan 2018
Bob | June 2018 | Jan 2018
Bob | June 2018 | Mar 2018
Bob | July 2018 | Jan 2018
Bob | July 2018 | Mar 2018
```

I'd just like to count the number of different open accounts 'Bob' has at each (archive date) and at each (archive date-1).

So, for June 2018:

```
   At Archive Date, Bob has 2.
   At Archive Date-1, Bob only has 1.
```

Here's what I tried:

-- Because there's so much data and it's not just 'Bob', I'm a little confused.
This Makes sense for count of all open Account Dates at a particular Archive Date:
-- COUNT(Open Account Date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID Order by Archive) as CurrentArchive_Counts

But I can't Mix Lag with Count, so I don't think this works: 
-- Count(LAG(Open Account Date,1) OVER (Partition BY ID Order by Archive)) as PreviousArchive_Counts ??

Comment: Thanks bud, just using SQL Server

Comment: As you are new, is always good to say, what have you tried. People is not going to answer you the quiz, take  alook at SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE GROUP BY COLUMN

Comment: Thanks, still learning - i updated with what I tried.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need lag:. Look into ["Row/Range"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause of partitioning function. Check out Example D .

You will needed something along these lines:

```
SELECT *, COUNT() OVER( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Archive ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) AS AccountsNum,
COUNT() OVER( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Archive ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEEDING AND UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) AS LastArchiveAccountsNum,
FROM [table]
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, as I don't need the running total and just for the point in time- would just specifying say ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND CURRENT ROW)  or ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING do the trick?